# How do I use jQuery on an HTML document instead of the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify an HTML document, but its not the same as the DOM. However, I found that the syntax that I used with the DOM itself doesn't work with the other document. For example, I could find the title using `$("title")` with the DOM. However, with the document I have to use `doc.find("title")`. There are other, more involved changes and I'm stuck on how to proceed with this. Is there a reference I can look at? I know about the jQuery documentation, but that assumes that you're manipulating the DOM itself.

Comment: Can you explain your setup and environment in more detail? Are you working in a browser?

Comment: I'm working on a Chrome extension, so yes my code will run in-browser. I can definitely give more details - Is there anything specific that you'd like to know?

Comment: A HTML document is the same as the DOM. What is your "HTML document".

Comment: I have it as a variable in my JS code. I was trying to get a page that the DOM linked to, and then manipulate that. However, Andri's answer works pretty well so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've gathered the `$` function assumes it's default scope for selectors is the active document. if you create jQuery objects that are not in the body of the document, the `$(object).find(selector)` is your best way to select within that object. The rest of the functions should work fine, at least the ones dealing with selecting, transversing and manipulation.

I should add that if the object is a jQuery object, there is no need to use the $. All the jQuery functions will be available to that object. So if you create:

```
var obj = $('<div>some text</div>');
```

you can use `obj.addClass('cool)` to get a jQuery object containing

```
<div class="cool">some text</div>
```

Comment: Works really well! I wasn't using the `$(object)` part (only the objectname). Things seem to be working in a more expected fashion now. Thanks!

Comment: @efficiencyIsBliss Please see the added notes. Yo don't always need to use $.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery on your doc by using the following

```
$("title", doc)
```

You pass the string "doc" to jQuery and it will use that instead of the DOM